# Java multiplication of same number returns different output in Python

Tags: java, python, multiplication

I am porting some Java code to Python, but for some reason, the results differ.

**Java**

```
int vi = 3997125 * 3997125;

Output: -270075495
```

**Python**

```
vi = 3997125 * 3997125

Output: 15977008265625
```

How would I accomplish the same output Java returns in Python?

Comment: You want the wrong (overflow) result in python?

Comment: Yeah. A bit odd, I know. @MichaelSzczesny

Comment: In Java, an int is signed so that anything above 2^31 will be treated as a negative number. So if the output is > 2^31 then do 2^31 - (value) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simulate the conversion of a python integer to 32bit integer value with overflow

```py
def bit32(value):
    shift =  1 << 32
    return value % shift - shift if value.bit_length() >= 32 else value
bit32(3997125*3997125)
```

Out:

```
-270075495
```

Comment: Updated my answer to work with integers without overflow.

Answer (score 3):

The Java snippet [overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). To avoid this, you could use `long`s:

```java
long vi = 3997125L * 3997125L;
```

Answer (score 1):

The range of a variable declared as type `int` is -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 .

So when you do

```
3997125 * 3997125 = 15,977,008,265,625
```

which is out of range for a int type .

As suggested you can change the type to `long` .